# docker-compose crash on a fresh Raspbian installation

Tags: docker, docker-compose, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I just did a fresh installation of Docker and Compose on a Raspberry Pi3. Docker run fine. But when I try to do anything with Compose, I get this error

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ docker-compose
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
    from compose.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .formatter import ConsoleWarningFormatter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/formatter.py", line 15, in <module>
    from backports.shutil_get_terminal_size import get_terminal_size
ImportError: No module named shutil_get_terminal_size
```

Compose was installed through `pip`. Any idea what could be missing?

Comment: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9656 can you try `pip install --upgrade setuptools pip` and then `pip uninstall ipython
pip install ipython` or you check https://dev.to/rohansawant/installing-docker-and-docker-compose-on-the-raspberry-pi-in-5-simple-steps-3mgl

Comment: Or just pip `install --user ipython` on the rpi. Alternatively, run compose from a docker container with an appropriately configured image in it -- just remember to mount the docker socket `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`.

Answer (score 7):

Got the same issue today.
Did

```sh
sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
pip3 install docker-compose
```

Works like a charm.